# Chatbase: Aggregate Stats for All Bots

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbase

I have integrated Chatbase with Dialogflow and configured a couple of bots. Chatbase provides reports on individual bots but I would like to see the aggregate view from all bots. 
There are a couple of reports like Active Users, Links for which it makes sense to me see aggregate data to get overall user engagement with bots. As per my knowledge, it's not possible through the web interface but is it possible through the backdoor like API, downloading through CSV etc...?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to accomplish what you are asking by setting up a direct server to server integration to send you bot messages to the [Chatbase API](https://chatbase.com/documentation/generic). I have detailed the steps below:

1. Create a bot in Chatbase to obtain API key.
2. Set up a [direct server to server integration](https://chatbase.com/documentation/quickstart) to send all of your bot messages to the single api key (bot).
3. Use the version field of the API to denote from which bot each message originates.
4. You will then be given an aggregate view of all your bot's messages by default and you can use the [version filter](https://chatbase.com/documentation/report-filters#version) to see metrics for each individual bot.

Comment: Thank you Sean for the alternate approach. I would have chosen suggested approach unless I need to bifurcate stats based on the real bot version like 1.0, 1.1.